# How can we achieve Ruby on Rails MVC application with React Applicaiton on Same server (I will use API's from MVC Application only)?

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, configuration

I have Ruby on Rails MVC Application deployed into AWS server.
Using Ngnix and Passenger

But now I want to deploy react application deploy in same server with same domain using MVC application API's

How to configure Ngnix for react application to run both MVC and React Application with same backend

Here react is in different project folder